# Laravel receive array as request

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, laravel

In javascript, I do:

```
axios.post('/api/categories', {
   topCategories: JSON.stringify({ data: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] })
})
```

Then, in Laravel, I receive it:

```
protected function getCategories(Request $request) {
    $topCategories = $request->topCategories;
    var_dump(json_decode($topCategories));
}
```

However, I always receive null in `var_dump`! Why is this happening?

Comment: Use dd(json_decode($topCategories)) instead and check the results.

Comment: That's `null`! Is there another way to receive array in POST request?

Comment: `var_dump($request->topCategories['data']);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use JSON.stringify. Axios do it by itself.

```
axios.post('/api/categories', {
   topCategories: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
})
```

And for handling POST payload use `$request->input()` in Laravel.

```
protected function getCategories(Request $request) {
    $topCategories = $request->input('topCategories');
    dd($topCategories);
}
```

For being clear: the issue is not on the server side. You do everything correctly there and you can use `$request->topCategories` to retrieve data from POST payload. But ajax payload is built incorrectly.

Comment: And how do I convert this to array?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "this"? Axios will convert your payload object to JSON and send it to your server. Laravel will parse JSON and its fields will be available via `$request->input(<fieldName>)`. Thus after executing  `$topCategories = $request->input('topCategories');` you will have a correct PHP array in `$topCategories` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this. Hope this helps you.

```
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1440#issuecomment-379355382
```